# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocketServer'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, socketserver

Am using python 3.7.4 i have import socketserver in all lowercase but still am getting error

```
from flask import Flask,flash,redirect,render_template,request,sessions,abort
import socketserver
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world"
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocketServer'

Comment: Can you post full error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to run **boot.sh** before running the flask app.

Otherwise

```
try:
   import socketserver
   from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
   from http.server import HTTPServer
except ImportError:
   import SocketServer as socketserver
   from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
   from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
```